# Using CapsLock as a Modifier + Standalone Key in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, autohotkey

In Windows, you can use AutoHotKey to make Capslock a standalone key (say, binding it to 'escape') *as well as* a modifier (so that you can bind, say 'CapsLock + k', to launch a browser).

I've tried everything under sun to make CapsLock have its own special binding PLUS make it a modifier key in Ubuntu, but I'm convinced it's not possible.

Am I wrong? Does anyone know a way this could be possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Remap Caps Lock**

`Applications -> Keyboard Layout -> Options...`
`Caps Lock key behavior -> Make Caps Lock an additional ESC`

If you want it to be another modifier you could make it *an additional Hyper* for instance.

**Hotkeys**

As far as assigning shortcuts, nothing beats Compiz's Command plugin. Sadly, Unity seems to have crippled it. You can try your luck though.

`Applications -> Software & Updates -> [x] Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)`

*Open a terminal*

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
ccsm
```

`Applications -> CompizConfig Settings Manager -> Commands -> [x] Enable Commands`

*Set a hotkey:*

`Commands -> Key Bindings -> Run command 0 -> Disabled -> [x] Enabled -> Grab key combination`

*Set an action:*

`Commands -> Key Bindings -> Command line 0 -> <input command here>`